# efficient way to fill histogram array

Tags: python, optimization, histogram, vectorization

does anyone have an idea to make the following python code faster and maybe without the for loops or vectorizing it? i bet there is a trick or cool function in numpy to do this, but have not found a method yet.

"img" is a numpy image of uint8:

```
 histogram = np.empty((height, width, 256), dtype=np.uint16)
 max_bin = np.empty((height, width), dtype=np.uint16)
 while ...:
    img = ...
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            histogram[y, x, img[y, x]] += 1

    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            max_bin[y,x] = np.argmax(histogram[y, x])
```

Comment: ok, for the second part of the code, i replaced the two for-loops with the following vectorized code:
`max_bin = np.argmax(histogram, axis=2)`
for the histogram calculation above it I do not have a faster/vectorized solution yet :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `np.bincount` to do that, but it requires all the images to be loaded simultaneously (at least by chunks). In your case it is probably better to use the Numba's `@njit`.

If you have a lot of small images, you can do this operation in parallel using thread-local histograms and then sum these local histograms to get the result you want.